# Student on F1 visa with paid internship: How to estimate & file a tax return for refund?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, f1-student-visa

I'm on an F1 visa, and I did a paid internship for 7 months. My gross earnings was around $27K, and ~$4K was withheld for taxes.

On my pay stub, I see records for:

- Federal Income tax,
- California State Income tax,
- California State DI tax.

What is the approximate amount I can expect for a refund, and how should I file?

Comment: Don't they have a GLACIER account available for you at school? Check with the international students' office. https://www.online-tax.net/

Comment: I'm not sure about yours but GLACIER told me that I need to look for other ways to file state tax reports. They only do the fed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to estimate taxes is [SnapTax](https://turbotax.intuit.com/snaptax/mobile/) by Intuit. Although it files with TurboTax, which does not support F1 tax filing, you may want to enter your details just to see how much you could expect as a return – just don't file your taxes with it.

Comment: Except that F1 on internship will likely be cover by a treaty if one exist and not pay taxes, or pay very little. Calculating as resident will provide a significantly skewed answer.

Comment: TurboTax does support F1 tax filing.

Comment: @dacongy: it does not support the 1040NR-EZ form that F1 students have to fill. https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/1486172-i-am-on-f1-student-visa-can-i-use-turbotax

Comment: Looks like a great app. For some retarded reason, it cannot be installed in a foreign country though (I was in the US and now need to file from outside the US).